# Open header-files in editor based on content in corresponding source

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have several files that have the same name, but a different extension. For example

```
echo "array"   > A.hpp
echo "..."     > A.h
echo "content" > B.hpp
echo "..."     > B.h
echo "content" > C.hpp
echo "..."     > C.h
```

**I want to get a list of `*.h` files based on some content in the corresponding `*.hpp` file.** In particular I am looking for a one-liner to open them in my editor.

It is fair to assume that for each `*.hpp` file the corresponding `*.h` file exists. Also, since they are source files, it may be assumed that the filenames do not contain whitespaces.

---

#### Current approach

I know how to get a list of `*.hpp` files based on their content. An approach (but surely not the only or the best) is to

```
find . -type f -iname '*.hpp' -print | xargs grep -i 'content' | cut -d":" -f1
```

which gives

```
./B.hpp
./C.hpp
```

Opening in my editor is then done by

```
st `find . -type f -iname '*.hpp' -print | xargs grep -i 'content' | cut -d":" -f1`
```

But how can I get/open the corresponding `*.h` files?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: There's something I don't understand. You say that you are able to get -hpp files based on their content, but then, in the example, you get a .h file, not a .hpp...

Comment: This question is confusing. You want to get a list of files with the .h extensions based on what content in which file? You can replace the extensions with simple  `sed 's/\..*/.hpp/'` but i don't know if you want to find these files or change the output...

Comment: If I understand correctly, if `foo.hpp` contains the string `content`, you want something to print `foo.h`? Is that correct?

Comment: @Ed I have made the question completely self-contained

Comment: @Poshi Thanks. Sorry, my mistake. I have made the question fully self-contained and verifiable.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, that indeed could be simple solution!

Comment: @DanielH That is correct. I have edited my question to make this point more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to get a list of `*.h` files based on some content in the corresponding `*.hpp` file.

```
while read -r line ; do
  echo "${line%.hpp}.h"
done < <(grep -i 'content' *.hpp| cut -d":" -f1)
```

[BashFAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) recommends to use a `while` loop and `read` command to read a data stream.

**One-liner as requested**

```
st `while IFS= read -r line ; do echo "${line%.hpp}.h"; done < <(grep -i 'content' *.hpp| cut -d":" -f1)`
```

If you are dealing with filenames containing whitespace, you need to use `printf` instead of echo.

```
st `while IFS= read -r line ; do printf '%q' "${line%.hpp}.h"; done < <(grep -i 'content' *.hpp| cut -d":" -f1)`
```

The `%q` lets printf format the output so that it can be reused as shell input.

**Explanation**

You have to read it from behind. First we grep all files ending in `.hpp` in the current directory for the string `'content'` and cut everything but the basename. 
The while loop will read the output of grep and assign the basename to the variable `line`.

Inside the while loop we use bash's [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to change the file extension from `.h` to `.hpp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I need, end a very good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question still isn't clear but is this all you're trying to do (using GNU awk for `gensub()`)?

```
$ awk '/content/{print gensub(/[^.]+$/,"h",1,FILENAME)}' *.hpp
B.h
C.h
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You are probably right about the question. Can you be more specific as to what you find unclear, such that I can improve.

Comment: 1) Why are you using `cut`? 2) Why are you using `grep -i`? 3) Can your file names contain spaces? 4) Do we need to ensure the ".h" exists? etc...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have edited the question, I hope it is more clear now.